# Функция div для беззнаковых типов

Tags: c++, c

Почему в библиотеке нет функции `div` для беззнаковых типов, а есть только варианты для знаковых?

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/div

Достаточно ли такой реализации?

```
return {x / y, x % y};
```

Comment: Скорее всего эта функции была придумана в те времена, когда результат деления со знаковыми операндами был implementation-defined. Хоть сейчас результат деления однозначно определён, функция сохранилась из соображений совместимости.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, я бы скорее про производительность думал - два значения одной операцией. Хотя сейчас компилятор и сам разберётся.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да производительность тоже сыграла свою роль, но основная мотивация - чётко-определённое поведение при делении знаковых целых. Это кстати объясняет, почему нет беззнаковой версии данной функции. См.: [What is the purpose of the div() library function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11726016)

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл, тогда ответ пиши :)

Answer (score 0):

В смысле достаточности - да, достаточно, но отнюдь не необходимо.

Эта функция появилась в С давно, когда еще экономили такты, а оптимизаторы были не такими крутыми, так что программисты вынуждены были оптимизировать сами.

Деление было очень дорогостоящим, причем часто результат и деления, и остатка получались с помощью одной одной (длинной по времени) комендой процессора. Так что если нужны были оба значения - можно было СИЛЬНО сэкономить на тактах процессора.

А дальше - как обычно: обратная совместимость.

Comment: Но почему нет такой же для беззнаковых это не объясняет.

Comment: Потому что беззнаковые типы появились, вероятно, позже. когда это уже было не актуально :)

Comment: Нет, беззнаковые типы были изначально.